# How to organize member field classes to use the base class in C#?

Tags: c#, class

I have a class called `Gas` which keeps basic information about the specific gas:

```
public class Gas {
    public float molarMass;
    public float heatCapacity;

    public float GetPartialPressure() {}
    public float GetMass() {}
    public float GetMassPercentage() {}
}
```

I also have a class called `RoomAir` which includes a list of `Gas`'es and a `Dictionary<Gas, float>`, which stores every gas in the air of that specific room and its volume percentage.

```
public class RoomAir {
    public float roomVolume;
    public float pressure;

    public List<Gas> gases;
    public Dictionary<Gas, float> gasVolPercentage;
}
```

Unfortunately all of the methods of `Gas` require information about other gases in a room and the room's volume.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void Main() {
        Gas nitrogen;
        nitrogen.molarMass = 0.028f;
        Gas oxygen;
        oxygen.molarMass = 0.032f;

        RoomAir earthAir;
        earthAir.roomVolume = 100f;
        earthAir.gases.Add(nitrogen);
        earthAir.gasVolPercentage.Add(nitrogen, 0.78f);
        earthAir.gases.Add(oxygen);
        earthAir.gasVolPercentage.Add(oxygen, 0.22f);

        earthAir.gases[0].GetMass(); // can't be done, as the nitrogen Gas would need
                                     // information about earthAir volume etc.
    }
}
```

**Is there any proper workflow for the `Gas` class to use variables from the correct `RoomAir` object?**

Additionaly: is it possible to tweak things up so that I could reach `Gas` members using `gases.oxygen`instead of `gases[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just add as a parameter of your GetMass method a volume?

```
public float GetMass(float roomVolume) {}
```

And then just pass the earth air volume

```
earthAir.gases[0].GetMass(earthAir.roomVolume);
```

Comment: GetMass() needs volume percentage and other variables from the RoomAir too, it wouldn't be clear if we had to pass all the variables to each function.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you create a new gas, you should require a reference to `RoomAir` to be passed into the constructor.

Your code is missing the construction of the `Gas` object, but do this:

```
Gas nitrogen;
nitrogen = new Gas(roomAir);
nitrogen.molarMass = 0.028f;
```

Store the reference to `roomAir` in your `Gas` object - obviously you'll have to construct the `roomAir` first. Since it's a reference any other changes you do to the room air will reflect in the gas object.

It's pretty standard to give objects a link to their parent (usually called `Parent`), and their parent is generally a container.

Your `GetMass()` method can then do `Parent.gases` to get other gases in the room.

This solution would work but I really don't think it's a nice one. I think a better solution would be to put GetMass onto the `RoomAir` class and keep the `Gas` classes totally dumb.

Since the mass of the nitrogen has nothing to do with the nitrogen itself, it is really something you have to examine the room to find, it makes more sense to put `GetMass()` on the `RoomAir` class, and give call it with a parameter such as `GetMass("Nitrogen")`.

Comment: This is a way, but it wouldn't allow me to create another room with nitrogen too (at least I would need to create `Gas nitrogen1` etc. just to put the gas in the other room)

Comment: I've edited my answer which might help a bit, if by accident. If nitrogen is fixed and to be used in lots of places you probably don't want to make instances of it, you might be better off using a Singleton or static class, in fact, I think an enum would be better combined with a singleton with a static class to return information about it. `GasEnum.Nitrogen` for example.